# Server-side commenting in asp.net (HTML side)

Tags: asp.net

I need to leave some instructional comments for other developers on a page/user control.  Is there a better way to do this besides the below?

```
  <% /* DO NOT rename control IDs here, because blah blah blah... */ %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%-- Comment Here --%>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is about it, barring a HTML comment.

Your options are:

```
 <!-- Renders to ClientOutput too -->
```

or:

```
 <% /* Your original idea */ %>
```